# Determining whether STDERR is going to terminal

Tags: java, linux, command-line-interface, stderr, io-redirection

I have a suite of Java programs which are used as command-line tools on our Linux servers. Most of them use a class that prints a progress bar on STDERR, similar to Perl's `Term::ProgressBar`.

I'd like to have the progress bar shown whenever STDERR is going to the terminal and automatically disable itself when STDERR is redirected so that there aren't all sorts of progress bar pieces in the redirected data.

Checking `System.console() == null` was my first thought, but redirecting STDOUT is enough to make this `true`, even if STDERR is still going to the terminal. Is there anything I can check that is specific to STDERR? A solution that is Linux-specific or that uses native APIs would be ok for my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Enjoy

Comment: @UberDoyle I'm not asking about launching another process using Java. I want to know whether the STDERR of the *current* process is being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `isatty(3)`, in `unistd.h`. There's no way to tell whether a file handle has been redirected, period, but that'll tell you whether it's still interactive. See the source for the `tty` command in GNU coreutils.

Comment: Do you know which function in ioctl I should be looking at? Nothing stands out to me after reading the [`ioctl`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/ioctl.2.php), [`tty_ioctl`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man4/tty_ioctl.4.php), and [`console_ioctl`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man4/console_ioctl.4.php) man pages.

Answer (score 0):

After combining [@chrylis's pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18338820/446591) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987567/446591) and doing a little tweaking, what I finally ended up with is:

1. create and compile Java class with native method signature
2. use `javah` to generate C header file
3. create `.cpp` file, implementing function with `isatty`
4. compile C++ code into shared library
5. run Java program, using `-Djava.library.path=...` to tell it where your custom library is

Java class:

```
package com.example.cli;

class LinuxTerminalSupport {

    public native boolean isStderrVisible();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("term");
    }
}
```

ant target to generate `.h`:

```
<target name="generate-native-headers">
    <javah destdir="native/" verbose="yes">
        <classpath refid="compile.class.path"/>
        <class name="com.example.cli.LinuxTerminalSupport" />
    </javah>
</target>
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "com_example_cli_LinuxTerminalSupport.h"
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_cli_LinuxTerminalSupport_isStderrVisible(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    return isatty(fileno(stderr)) == 1;
}
```

`Makefile` (change java includes to reflect your `$JAVA_HOME`):

```
linux: LinuxTerminalSupport.o
    g++ -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_13/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_13/include/linux \
            -o libterm.so -shared -Wl,-soname,term.so LinuxTerminalSupport.o -lc

LinuxTerminalSupport.o: LinuxTerminalSupport.cpp
    g++ -c -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_13/include -I/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_13/include/linux LinuxTerminalSupport.cpp
```

Comment: You didn't need to create a library for this (see [NOT INVENTED HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here#In_computing)). isatty() is already part of the export table of the glibc binaries and could be found via /lib64/libc.so.6 or /lib/lib.so.6 (Also, please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually)

Comment: @user2284570 - I *did* use `isatty`. If you know how to use native libraries without the JNI wrapper then you should tell us-- I've never seen any information regarding that.

Comment: @BradMace user doesn't have any idea what he's talking about.