# How can you detect whether Java System.out is a terminal?

Tags: java, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a Java program's input/output streams are connected to a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-termi)

I'd like to be able to have a problem behave differently when being run interactively versus in an automated way.  In Python, you can use `sys.stdout.isatty` to detect this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077113/how-do-i-detect-whether-sys-stdout-is-attached-to-terminal-or-not)).  Is there an equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 2):

One option is for the automated way to define a system property on the command line. For example: `-Dcom.xyz.automated=true.`