# Is it possible to detect where output goes - to terminal or into pipe/file?

Tags: java, scala, io, jvm

For example, when I'm writing program that outputs text to stdout and uses colors (via escape sequences), I would like to disable those colors if output goes to other program (like `less`, `grep`) or to file, since color codes mess up the output.

Is it possible to do it from Java process?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-term - the short answer appears to be "no"...

Comment: Why not provide an argument that can be passed on the command line to invoke plain text mode (or to enable color mode depending on which mode is used more often)?

Comment: @Sticks - Well, it could be possible - but is well too obvious to ask this question if that would be an acceptable solution :) Digging through tens of options just to get to that option is not good, so I wanted to get some automatic way to do it.

Comment: @TomSeddon - Actually, that question seems to give "yes" answer - System.console() works for me at the moment :)

Comment: @Rogach You might want to describe how you've solved the problem using System.console() as an answer to your own question to help future readers who would face the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it in a following way (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-term)):

[System.console()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()) will return `Console` object, if there is some terminal connected to application, and it will return `null` if you pipe output into other app or save it to file.

Thus it becomes a simple check:

```
if (System.console() == null) {
  // ... no console, print dull plaintext
} else {
  // we have a console, now we can output colors as well
}
```

(tested on Linux Mint 10)