# Writing to stdout, also print the inputs supplied like a real terminal

Tags: java, linux, shell, io-redirection

Let's have a simple Java application where I have the following code to scan for user input:

```
Scaner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
int value = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered: " + value);
```

When I manually run it, as expected I see what I type, a sample run would be:

```
Enter the value: 3
You entered: 3
```

However, when I have a file with content

```
3
```

And I want to redirect the programs stdout to a file by this:

```
java Test < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

All I get is in `cat OUTPUT`:

```
Enter the value: You entered: 3
```

As the values inputted are not shown on the stdout, which is correct, they are not on stdout, I know, I see them because I manually type them to my terminal. But how can I make them also seen when I redirect the stdout like that?

**Edit:**
I can see that code is making a `read(0,` syscall.

```
$ (strace -ff -e trace=read -e read 2>&1 java Test < INPUT) | grep "read(0,"
[pid  7297] read(0, "3\n", 8192)        = 2
```

Is there a better way to intercept it?

**Edit 2:**
I mean, the OUTPUT should be the following when I run it with `java < INPUT > OUTPUT`

```
Enter the value: 3
You entered: 3
```

Comment: Detect whether the input is a TTY (terminal), and if it's not, print the input data manually. Maybe detecting in Java is not so easy, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-term . (In most other languages this feature is built in.)

Comment: I don't want to make modifications to the supplied code, they are coming from outside.

Comment: If you don't want to change the supplied code, what other options are OK for you?

Comment: Anything but changing the supplied code. I can write another program, script to run the given code, and handle the input/output redirection differently. Maybe detect when the `java Test` is wanting input, and at that time write the content of INPUT to both OUTPUT and STDIN to file, but I am wondering if there is another, easier way, I feel like I am inventing the wheel.

Comment: Detecting when the `java Test` is wanting input is impossible. You can look at what it prints, and from that you can deduce when it most probably wants input.

Comment: Most probably there is no easier way than writing the driver. Let's see if someone proposes a way. You may also try the program named `expect`, but I don't know it well enough to say if it can print what you want.

Comment: It is not impossible, you can monitor syscalls with strace, I edited my answer with that command.

Comment: The strace idea is great, but it doesn't make the solution much simpler. I've extended my answer.

Comment: I've just tried it: even `strace` can't say that the program is waiting for input. `strace` prints `read(0, ` if the program is waiting for input, but also when input is available, and the program is reading it. To distinguish, one should measure the time how long `strace` is stuck at `read(0, `. If it's long enough, then it's most probably waiting. These timeouts would make the method very flaky.

Comment: I've modified my comment and added a `strace`-based script.

Comment: @Mustafa: care to comment on my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify the supplied code, but you can modify the way you launch it.

What do I offer is a hack that assumes change in System.in. What did I do:

1) I made a test program with single `main` method with code you post. I launched it:

```
$ java -cp dist/Test.jar test.Test <input 
Enter the value: You entered: 3
```

2) I wrote a java programm that does

1. redirect input stream (System.in)
2. launch test.Test.main

code:

```
package redirecter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Redirecter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final InputStream oldIn = System.in;
        InputStream hackedIn = new InputStream() {

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                int b = oldIn.read();
                System.out.write(b);
                return b;
            }

            @Override
            public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                int res = oldIn.read(b, off, len);
                System.out.write(b, off, res);
                return res;
            }
        };
        System.setIn(hackedIn);

        test.Test.main(args);
    }
}
```

3) I launched old code with a new way:

```
$ java -cp dist/Test.jar:../Redirecter/dist/Redirecter.jar redirecter.Redirecter <input 
Enter the value: 3
You entered: 3
```

Supplied code wasn't edited; it was just launched by tricky way. All the parameters and jvm options were saved. If you have several entry points, you may use reflection instead of simple call to `test.Test.main(args);`

Bad point: if someone will edit `System.in` in supplied code, the hack will be broken. But it seems to be safe until you work with standard input.

Comment: Although it is specific to java, it does not modify the given code and it gave me an idea, I am willing to implement this generic in generic form and post soon, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Write another program, let's call it driver, call `new Process()` in the driver, execute this program in the process, connect the stdin to and stdout to the driver. As soon as the process writes `Enter new value:`, make the driver send the value from the input file etc. Make the driver print both its input and output.

Another option is that the driver runs the process within `strace` (Linux-specific), monitoring `read(0, ...)` calls.

Here is a solution in Perl (`rtrace.pl`) which uses 0.1 second as a timeout with strace:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use integer;
use strict;
$^F = 0x7fffffff;  # Disable close-on-exec on pipe().
my $input_filename = shift;
my $if;
die if !open($if, '<', $input_filename);
my($r,$w);
die if !pipe($r,$w);
my($sr,$sw);
die if !pipe($sr,$sw);
my $pid=fork();
die if !defined $pid;
if (!$pid) {
  close($if);
  close($w);
  close($sr);
  if (fileno($r)) { die if !open STDIN, '<&', $r; close($r); }
  die if !exec 'strace', '-o', '/proc/self/fd/' . fileno($sw), '-s', '4',
      '-e', 'trace=read', '--', @ARGV;
}
close($r);
close($sw);
{ my $old = select($w); $| = 1; select($old); }
$| = 1;
my($s,$got);
L: for (;;) {
  die if !defined($got = sysread($sr, $s, 4096));
  last if !$got;
  if ($s =~ /^read\(0, \Z(?!\n)/m) {
    { my $rin = '';
      vec($rin, fileno($sr), 1) = 1;
      $got = select($rin, undef, undef, .1);
      next L if $got;
    }
    $s = <$if>;
    if (!length($s)) {
      close($w);
      close($if);
    } else {
      print $s;
      print $w $s;
    }
  }
}
die if $pid != waitpid($pid, 0);
exit $?;
```

To use it:

```
$ chmod +x rtrace.pl
$ ./rtrace.pl INPUT java Test >OUTPUT
```

You may want to add `-ff` to the `strace` argument list for Java.

Please note that there can be deadlock issues if lines are long. This issues can be resolved by adding input buffering after `sysread`.

Comment: I added `-ff` so it can watch the forks, but it says: `$ ./rtrace.pl INPUT java Test >OUTPUT
strace: Can't fopen '/proc/self/fd/7.2134': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more engineering cycles to contribute to this. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe there is an easy answer for the `7.2134` problem: Try `strace -f` instead of `strace -ff`.

Answer (score 1):

Not compiled/tested (yet):

```
class EchoInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream echoOut;

    public void EchoInputStream(InputStream in, OutputStream echoOut) {
        this.in = in;
        this.echoOut = out;
    }

    // Reads the next byte of data from in and echos to echoOut
    public int read() {
        int r = in.read();
        echoOut.write(r);
        return r;
    }

    // Reads a bytes from in, stores them into the buffer array b and echos to echoOut.
    int read(byte[] b) {
        in.read(b);
        echoOut.write(b);
    }

    // Reads up to len bytes of data from in into array b and echos them to echoOut.
    int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
        in.read(b, off, len);
        echoOut.write(b, off, len);
    }

  void reset() {
    in.reset();
  }

  // for other abstract methods, simply redirect to in
}
```

To use:

```
Scaner scan = new Scanner(new EchoInputStream(System.in, System.out));
System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
int value = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered: " + value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer:

1. Save this script as, say `wrap.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while read -s input_line
   do
       raw_out=$(echo $input_line | $1) 
       header=${raw_out%%:*}:
       echo -e ${raw_out/$header/$header$input_line\\n}
   done < ${2:-/proc/${$}/fd/0}
   ```
2. `chmod +x wrap.sh`
3. use it like so: `./wrap.sh 'java yourprog' inputfile.txt` with input files having as many numbers as you want, one per line.
4. Remember the mandatory quotes around `'java yourprog'`
5. If you want to use it interactively, you still can (just ommit the input file):

   ```
   $ ./wrap.sh 'java yourprog'
   Enter number:12345
   You entered: 12345
   ```
6. You can also redirect like this: `./wrap.sh 'java yourprog' > outfile.txt`, but input whoud be invisible, only present in the `outfile.txt`.

Final words:

1. Requirement: your program is expected to ask a question like **"Enter number:"** or **"Enter value:"** (just like in your code) that contains a colon!.
2. tested it with my toy C prog - there's no need to launch java so it looks prettier:)
3. This can be of course massaged much more, but it provides the basic functionality you asked for.

Comment: It is nice hack but it relies on presence of colon

Comment: Well, it can rely on some different separator. You haven't specified a requirement that it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think named pipes, coprocesses, or process substitution in bash/zsh could solve your issue. Here is a hacky workaround in bash using process substitution. Basically you would loop over your input one line at a time, redirecting it once to your EXE, and once again to your output. The sleeps make sure everything gets ordered correctly.

```
 exec 6> >(./TEST.exe)
 sleep 1
 while read x; do
      echo $x
      sleep 1                                                                                                     
      echo $x >&6
      sleep 1
 done < INPUT.txt
```