# Determine whether the parent process is a terminal

Tags: java, c++, linux

I have a C++ program and I want to determine whether the parent process is a terminal or not. Because if it is a terminal, I can use escape codes to highlight the output, else this will be displayed with unreadable characters.
The solution need to run on any posix system.

If anyone knows the solution for Java I would be interested in it as well.

Comment: I think there's something in POSIX that can do this, but I can't recall the specifics. Possibly `fcntl()`? I didn't see anything relevant in the man entry though, so maybe it's something else.

Comment: @celticminstrel according to the man page `fcntl` stands for `file control` and doesn't seem to be what I want

Comment: I'm sorry, but *parent process is a terminal* is just non sense. Do you mean *standard output is a terminal*, *parent process is an interactive shell* or anything else ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're looking at it from the wrong angle.  Ask not what your parent process is, but rather what the capabilities of `stdout` are.  And to do that in a POSIX environment, use `isatty()`.

For stdout, `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)` should return `1`.

In Java, `System.console()` will apparently return a `Console` object if both stdin and stdout are a terminal, and `null` otherwise.  See [How can I check if a Java program's input/output streams are connected to a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-term) for more details.