# Detect java program started from crontab

Tags: java, cron

On a Redhat OS, I have a script that launches a Java program. This script can be started from the command line but is launched (periodically) by crontab as well.
Within this program, I need to know how the program was started. This because the output is written either to STDOUT (if started from the command line) or in a logfile (if launched by crontab).

First I thought I could use `System.console()`.
The problem is that this method returns `null` also if the program was started from the command line but with STDIN and/or STDOUT redirected.

Any idea how to resolve this?
I tried [How can I check if a Java program's input/output streams are connected to a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403772/how-can-i-check-if-a-java-programs-input-output-streams-are-connected-to-a-term) but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of options:

1. Add a `-Dcron=1` command line option when running from cron, to set a property that can be checked
2. Add a simple argument to the command line when running from cron and check it by looking in the `args[]` array
3. Set an environment variable in the script and check it in the program.

Comment: I already suspected it couldn't be done automatically. I go for the second option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable that you set in the cron job before starting the java program. Query the environment variable inside your program.