# How to check if a Java application is running within a Terminal window (System.in/System.out are available)

Tags: java, input, cmd, output

I basically want to check if the user can enter inputs and see outputs.

assuming we create a jar from this java application

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      System.out.println("enter input");
      Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("You entered: " + scn.nextLine();
   }
}
```

When I run this as a jar file the application will just run in the background waiting for input forever, unless we run the application in an environment that supports I/O like a cmd or an IDE window,the user will see nothing and will not be able to enter any input

> So how I can check if the user is able to see or give inputs(System.in and System.out are available)?

edit: this answer has fixed my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403817/10387008

Comment: I think _you_ will need to tell the program if it is running in the background or not via a command line argument or such when starting it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How?,I didn't understand..

Comment: ok i think i got the answer, thanks anyway; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403817/10387008